# Mixpanel - How to sort users by descending datetime of a certain activity

Tags: analytics, mixpanel

I have around 100 users in my Mixpanel (each having distinct_id), and I send events A, B , C for users as and when they do specific things in the UI

How can sort users by the descending datetime of their performance of activity associated with an event, say event A?

The last seen property of an user gets updated only when i add or update a property of an user.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it's [not possible to relate event data to individual user profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26934212/users-who-have-performed-an-action-in-mixpanel):

> As of now, People and Engagement are two separate data sets. We're working on tying these data sets together more tightly, but for the moment they are not seamlessly integrated.

The workaround is to update the Mixpanel user profile every time you trigger an event and store the current date as a property like "LastTimeEventTriggered - ViewHomepage".

The easiest way to do this is by using a wrapper function instead of `mixpanel.track`:

```
function trackEvent(eventName, data){
   mixpanel.track(eventName, data);
   mixpanel.people.set({"LastTimeEventTriggered - " + eventName, new Date()})
}

trackEvent("ViewHomepage", {})
```